# Sending a application/x-www-form-urlencoded list on html

Tags: html, list, post, jersey

I need to send an HTTP Post request to a RESTful service written in Java and uses Jersey.
My java function that handles request is like that:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response update(@FormParam("items") List<String> items) {

 ...

}
```

How can a create a request on html and send it, so that they are passed to my function as a List of String objects?